# How to provide a username and password to a GCE VM Windows instance at deployment time?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-compute-engine

Google Cloud seems pretty defensive on this. When creating a Windows VM instance in GCP you can have it create a username for you (the only one that is enabled by the way).

To get into the box, you need to let GCP generate a password for you. This workflow is not very Ansible friendly. I would ideally create a bunch of Windows VM instances in GCP, and then use one credential to access those machines to do automation inside, all from playbooks.

I hoped I could do something with the metadata construct in GCP as that seems to be the way to communicate with the guest inside the instances. There is no documentaton to be found on password setting using this. The closest thing I found was [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation) but it is all about generating a random password, while I am seeking to set a password.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try to add [ssh-key](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#edit-ssh-metadata) at the project level to just use one access to the instances and then if you want perform some task automatically after deploy you can use [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) to windows instances. I hope you can find helpful this information